# Powerbuilder-Cannot create new datawindow

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

I have problem with powerbuilder 12 build 5530. I can't to create new datawindow. After I click New->Datawindow->tabular or etc. The Window closed but after that there is not creating new datawindow. I also can't open properties of target sample. What is the problem with my installation? i've tried to re-install but the problem still same. Please help me...

PS: sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

What happens to a datawindow external ?, if not, then it can be a problem in some dll of connection to the database.

Comment: i cannot create datawindow external too.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by problems with the path setting on your machine. The path has a maximum length and once you hit it you can start having problems. A corrupted path will also cause problems. Rather than telling you what you need in the path I suggest you uninstall PowerBuilder then clean up your path. Often I find the same directories listed two or 3 times. Also make sure all of the directories in the path are valid and that the syntax is correct. After your path is clean reinstall PowerBuilder.